# What is the simplest way to add a value to state using material-ui form dialog?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

The [sample code from the material-ui form dialog](https://material-ui.com/components/dialogs/#form-dialogs), copied below, generates a form dialog asking a user to enter their email.

When a user clicks on the button `subscribe` In the modal (pop-up)... what is the simplest way to add that email value to state using functional React components?

(NB - clearly 'simplest' is subjective - so I'm going to go for least additional code, but feel free to use your own definition).

```js
import React from 'react';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import Dialog from '@material-ui/core/Dialog';
import DialogActions from '@material-ui/core/DialogActions';
import DialogContent from '@material-ui/core/DialogContent';
import DialogContentText from '@material-ui/core/DialogContentText';
import DialogTitle from '@material-ui/core/DialogTitle';

export default function FormDialog() {
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);

  const handleClickOpen = () => {
    setOpen(true);
  };

  const handleClose = () => {
    setOpen(false);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Button variant="outlined" color="primary" onClick={handleClickOpen}>
        Open form dialog
      </Button>
      <Dialog open={open} onClose={handleClose} aria-labelledby="form-dialog-title">
        <DialogTitle id="form-dialog-title">Subscribe</DialogTitle>
        <DialogContent>
          <DialogContentText>
            To subscribe to this website, please enter your email address here. We will send updates
            occasionally.
          </DialogContentText>
          <TextField
            autoFocus
            margin="dense"
            id="name"
            label="Email Address"
            type="email"
            fullWidth
          />
        </DialogContent>
        <DialogActions>
          <Button onClick={handleClose} color="primary">
            Cancel
          </Button>
          <Button onClick={handleClose} color="primary">
            Subscribe
          </Button>
        </DialogActions>
      </Dialog>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on the textField, add an onChange which stores the value entered in the email textfield to state; on subscribe, you can use this value simply to do further processing

changes to the sandbox provided in the link in your question:

```
          // Added this to state
          const [emailValue, setEmailValue] = React.useState("");

          <TextField
            autoFocus
            margin="dense"
            id="name"
            label="Email Address"
            type="email"
            onChange={(e) => setEmailValue(e.target.value)}
            fullWidth
          />
```

sample [code link here](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-8tx93)